# git log first 10 commits plus allow scrolling further commits

Tags: git, less

If I type

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
```

my complete screen is folded with all the commit that fits on the screen and I can scroll down/up further/older commits with j/k.

If I type

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate -n 10
```

then only the first 10 commits are displayed, but there is now scrolling option.

Is there a "easy" way to log only the first 10 commits plus additionally allow to scroll down further commits? Something like

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate | less --window=10
```

Thanks for the help

Zlatan

Comment: No, it is not possibile.

Comment: The easy way is to make an alias with your log-to-less command. `git config --global alias.logl '!git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate | less --window=10'` (mind the `!` to send that to the shell rather than to git, since there's a pipe). Then just `git logl`

Comment: `alias.lg10` the pun with decimal logarithm intended :-)

Comment: press 'G' (capital) to scroll to the end